# Show $\vec{x} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are elements of $l^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show $\vec{x} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are elements of $l^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

where $l^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of sequences $\vec{x} = (x_n)$, for which:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  |x_n|^2 < \infty$$

And the euclidean norm is given by $\|\vec{x}\|_2 = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty  |x_n|^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

I am not sure how to answer this. I can see the sequence is bounded $(0, 1]$ and the euclidean distance is probably 1 but I don't know how to show any of this.

Comment: Define $\;l^2(\Bbb R)\;$ , please. If that is the space of all square summable sequence then $\;\vec x\;? is *not * in it...but maybe it is defined otherwise.

Comment: I have edited the question, thanks.

Comment: you can use \sum instead of \sigma

Comment: Are you sure there shouldn't be a square on each term in the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After @Sine of the Time pointed it out in a comment, I noticed that what you call $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ is (almost, the norm is slightly different) what is usually referred to as $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$. It is still the case that it is not in this space. Indeed we can use the integral test for convergence of positive series, and observe that

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{\xi\to\infty}2(\sqrt{\xi}-1)=\infty,$$

implying that

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}=\infty.$$

Alternatively you can use comparison with the harmonic series.

---

**Original answer**

It is in fact **not** in $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$, as

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\right)^2=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{j}=\infty$$

is the harmonic series, which is well known diverges to infinity. It might be worth noting that if $p>2$, then it **is** in $\ell^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: OP is using an unusual definition of $\ell^2$

Comment: @SineoftheTime It is still not in $\ell^2$, even with that definition.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I know, maybe OP made a typo

Comment: @SineoftheTime thanks for pointing it out, it's quite a strange definition

Comment: I think the OP made a typo and it must the square summable sequence, or else it is the space $\;\ell^1(\Bbb R)\;$ , as pointed out by Lorago